# Moving a shared_ptr<StructA> into a shared_ptr<variant<StructA, StructB>>

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I'm trying to avoid a rather complex inheritance chain for a set of plain old data structs, but I need to store them all in a vector + share ownership with the caller.

```cpp
Struct A {};
Struct B {};

using TInstruction = std::variant<A, B>;

struct holder {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TInstruction>> items;
};

static holder h;

// Every individual TInstruction gets its own add function, for validation purposes
void add(std::shared_ptr<A> a) {
  // Somehow add this to h, while still sharing ownership with the caller
  // h.emplace_back(???)
}


int main() {
  holder h;

  auto a = std::make_unique<A>();
  auto b = std::make_unique<B>();

  add(a);
  // add(b) // not implemented
}
```

I've had moderate (but annoyingly poor) success with the following changes to the original idea:

1. Use shared pointers inside the variant, i.e. `using TInstruction = std::variant<std::shared_ptr<A>, std::shared_ptr<B>>`
2. Accepting a std::weak_ptr in `add()` and use `.lock()` to turn it into a std::shared_ptr

I don't mind #2 (it seems to me that it might be the right way to do it), but keeping the shared_ptr inside the variant inside of "outside" of it leads to some very verbose code and pattern matching.

Is it possible to do this at all? I essentially want to change the type of the shared pointer, but still express the idea of shared ownership.

Comment: Maybe you can make use of the "aliasing constructor" (#8 on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)). Though the example it gives is kind of the opposite of what you want. It would be straightforward to use if you already had a shared pointer to the variant and wanted to create a shared pointer to the inner object having the same ownership. But the other way around might not be possible with this.

Comment: Actually, how do you intend to put the object inside the variant? The variant would either have its own copy of it, or the object would be moved into it. In either case, why does it still need to share ownership with the caller? It sounds to me like option 1 is your only choice if you really want to have the same object in the variant.

Comment: A variant of shared pointers is definitely the "right" way to go about this. What about it is verbose? There's probably ways to cut down on that.

Comment: @Kevin & @HTNW thank you, looks like the question is a little silly, and I do get why it is :) The API intends to allow the user to just say `.add(<reference_to_shared_ptr>)` with a bunch of different types, so that parts more or less solved.

I have to "pattern match" on these types in several parts of the code, which is where it gets rather verbose to spell out the `variant.get<shared_ptr<StructType>>(var)` every time. But I'll take that hit. I knew the question was weird but I'm far from an expert so I wanted to reach out here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, this is a somewhat silly question because the variant has to be the owner of the object for the final type to be `shared_pointer<variant>`. Nevin's suggestion would work but uses the `void` type, which has its own problems (perhaps one could use the any type? that wouldn't be better.)

In the end I'm looking to keep as much type-safety as possible and also make the ownership model clear, so I will settle for a variant of shared pointers.

Comment: What problems does `shared_ptr<void>` have?  It still owns the object and knows how to reference count it, delete it correctly if it is the last reference and goes out of scope, is `reset()`, etc.

Comment: @Nevin I might be wrong, but I need to know the exact type inside the variant. I'm assuming that shared_ptr<void> is pretty type unsafe (even if one could write potentially safe code with it.)

Comment: It is as type safe as `std::any`, because they both use type erasure under the covers. You do have to keep track of the exact type in order to get it back out, which you can do the same way that `variant` does; namely, an index into the list of types. You don't need the exact type for destroying it correctly when the refcount goes to 0, as `shared_ptr` does that correctly for you even when you have both `shared_ptr<void>` and `shared_ptr<T>` pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `variant`, you could take advantage of `shared_ptr<void>` being able to hold a `shared_ptr` to anything, as long as you keep track of the type it is holding yourself, as in:

```
// Generic typelist
template <typename...>
struct Types;

// Find the 0-based index of type T in Types<...>
template <typename, typename>
struct Index;

// T is the first type in Types<...>
template <typename T, typename... Us> 
struct Index<T, Types<T, Us...>> : std::integral_constant<int, 0> {}; 

// T is not the first type in Types<...>
template <typename T, typename U, typename... Us> 
struct Index<T, Types<U, Us...>>
    : std::integral_constant<int, 1 + Index<T, Types<Us...>>()> {}; 

template <typename... Ts> 
struct SharedPtrVariant {
    template <typename T>
    explicit SharedPtrVariant(std::shared_ptr<T> p)
        : sp(std::move(p)), index(Index<T, Types<Ts...>>()) {}

    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> get() const {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(
            Index<T, Types<Ts...>>() == index ? sp : nullptr);
    }   

   private:
    std::shared_ptr<void> sp; 
    int index;
};
```